# jpa display actual sql query for only one Query

Tags: openjpa

I couldn't use

```
  SQL=TRACE
```

since, there so many queries executed each second, but wish to see the same result for only one Query.

Is there anyway to get this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do this via configuration. Perhaps you could write a custom [JDBCListener](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/docbook/manual.html#openjpa.jdbc.JDBCListeners) and try to log only the SQL you care about? Good luck!